# Proper escaping of double quotations for curl post data?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, curl, escape-characters

I'm trying to test out a server, by sending it JSON data and reading the response.

I need to `POST` data like `{"item":"value with spaces"}` but when I use `curl` I find that it sends the backslashes as well as the double quotes:

```
curl -d "{\"item\":\"value with spaces\"}" http://myserver.com/somerubyapp?get=stuff
```

The server actually receives `"{\"item\":\"value with spaces\"}"` including the double quotes on the ends of the string, the backslashes, and everything.

Am I using `curl` incorrectly, or is it an issue with my shell, bash?

Comment: Have you tried `curl -d '{"item":"value with spaces"}'`?

Comment: terdon's advice should work, because single quotes are supposed to negate any special characters between them: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/

Comment: Strangely enough, it adds quotes and backslashes if I do that.  `curl -d '{"item":"value with spaces"}'` is received by the server as `"{\"item\":\"value with spaces\"}"`

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I *seem* to remember that in curl the nested quoting works indeed the same way as in `alias` in bash. For instance, this is one of my many alias lines: `alias hdd='lsblk -nio KNAME,MODEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | grep -vi "\(1K\|sd[a-z][1-3]\s\+[0-9]\+,[0-9]G $\|swap\)"'`. It's always a battle with these nested ones: one mistake, and you may search for 15 minutes where the "bug" is.

Answer (score 6):

It's a kind of necroposting but I've had the same problem recently (with a different backend) and found that the reason is in a wrong Content-Type. By default it's "text/plain" or "text/html", and in my case `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ...` solved the issue.

Comment: necropost away my man. answer approved 

Answer (score 3):

What are you using server-side to print the parameters? It might well be an artefact from that method.

Both methods of quoting, .i.e. `"{\"...` and `'{"...` are ok.

Edit: I'll give you an example of the effect I'm hinting at:

```
% irb -r json
>> h = {"item" => "value with spaces"}    # (1)
=> {"item"=>"value with spaces"}          # (2)
>> h.to_json
=> "{\"item\":\"value with spaces\"}"     # (3)
>> puts(h.to_json)
{"item":"value with spaces"}              # (4)
=> nil
```

(1) defines a hashtable consisting of a single key with an associated value. irb shows you the result in (2), which is the hashtable again. Now when I look at the JSON representation of `h`, **irb** escapes the inner quotes in (3), while (4) shows that the backslashes are not "really" there.

So depending on *how* you print the parameters on the server, you might end up with the representation you showed us.

Comment: When I telnet directly into the server and do the http post by hand it goes through as expected. I don't believe the issue is on the server side.